# How to Import CSV file into MySQL without having data truncated

Tags: mysql

I am trying to import a CSV file into MySQL via the command line with following command :

```
USE database
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/TEMP/filename.csv' INTO TABLE tablename
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

But when I do that, the system will truncate all the data of some columns to a length of 10 characters. I have tried using the CHARACTER SET option (UTF8, LATIN1), but that did not help. I've also tried to save the initial CSV file differently.

An example of such data item in such column would be "*+00000000000@abc.de.fg;abdc=apcde,abcdefghijklmnop@qrs.tu.vw*" which will be truncated to +000000000 , sometimes when there is no number it will be truncated to "*abc@vgtw.c*" or similar.

How do I get the data to be imported without truncating anything, and have the data imported as is ?

Comment: What is datatype of column you are insert into?

Comment: @lad2025 : Sorry for the delay. The datatype of all columns is varchar, variable length. Sometimes varchar(15), varchar(20)

Comment: I mean that maybe your datatype cause data truncation

Comment: the collation is utf8_general_ci, if that helps. The length for the column that get's truncated is varchar(25)

Comment: @lad2025 : I've increased the size to varchar(50)